# full pyramid of stars

Tags: java

*Given an integer N, print a full pyramid of asterisks.*

A full pyramid of asterisks of size N has N lines of asterisks. The first line has **1 asterisk**, the second line has 2 asterisks, the third line has 3 asterisks and so on. Each asterisk has a space between them. The asterisks in each line are centered so as to make it look like a **pyramid**.
input 4

```
   *
  * *
 * * *
* * * *
```

output should be like this

```
import java.util.*;
public class solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n= sc.nextInt();
        int i,j,k,r;
        r=n;
        for(i=1;i<=r;i++){
            for(j=1; j<=r; j++){
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            n--;
            for(k=1; k<=i;k++){
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

output is not expected 
my out put is

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `r = n` and `n = sc.nextInt()`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
sorry there is a minor mistake i've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for padding each lines with prepending spaces should be to add `N - r -1` spaces to each line, starting with `r=0` for the first row.  So your `for` loop for doing that should be:

```
for (j=n-1; j >= 1; j--) {
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Just making this small change yields the following output for a height of 5:

```
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

Here is the full updated code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
int r = n;

for (int i=1; i <= r; i++) {
    for (int j=n-1; j >= 1; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    n--;
    for (int k=1; k<= i;k++) {
        System.out.print(" *");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```